# Accessability API broken in Windows 10 1809

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using the Accessability API to get the role when focus changes in external apps, for example Microsoft Edge, Firefox or Chrome. Until the October update to Windows the following code was working. After the update the role is always being reported as `ROLE_SYSTEM_CLIENT`

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the update?

```
    HWINEVENTHOOK objectFocusHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, NULL, &CMonitor::WinEventHookProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
```

then

```
void CALLBACK CMonitor::WinEventHookProc(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD idEventThread, DWORD time)
{
    if (event == EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS)
    {
        IAccessible* pAcc = nullptr;
        VARIANT varChild;

        if (SUCCEEDED(AccessibleObjectFromEvent(hwnd, idObject, idChild, &pAcc, &varChild)))
        {
            BSTR bstrName;
            VARIANT varRole;
            VARIANT varState;

            pAcc->get_accName(varChild, &bstrName);

            // after October update this always return ROLE_SYSTEM_CLIENT
            if (SUCCEEDED(pAcc->get_accRole(varChild, &varRole)))
            {
                if (varRole.lVal == ROLE_SYSTEM_TEXT)
                {
                    if (SUCCEEDED(pAcc->get_accState(varChild, &varState)))
                    {
                        // we do more with this  
                        bool isProtected = (varState.lVal & STATE_SYSTEM_PROTECTED) != 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            pAcc->Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue (probably), but you are leaking resources. Using [_bstr_t](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bstr-t-class) and [_variant_t](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/variant-t-class) will manage those resources for you.

Comment: good catch for the bstr - thanks

Comment: For what it's worth, using the Inspect.exe tool I can verify the behavior for Chrome. On Microsoft Edge it returns the expected values (as indicated by the code). I'm running Windows 10 Build 17763.rs5_release.180914-1434. Microsoft Edge reports version 44.17763.1.0.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by expected values - are you confirming its a bug?

Comment: Such a bug would be awfully hard not to notice since it would break about any program that depends on the api, there are many.  1809 was released in preview 8 months ago.  Do consider that this might be a bug in the accessibility provider.  A browser always needs to implement its own since it doesn't use standard OS widgets to enter text.  Do double-check that it goes wrong on multiple browsers, Chrome is pretty notorious.

Comment: Yes, I agree - but Microsoft Edge? That also used to work prior to the update. Getting Inspect.exe now ..

Comment: I was looking at the wrong values: MSAA returns `ROLE_SYSTEM_CLIENT` in Edge as well. The UI Automation interfaces return the correct (expected) values in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: @IInspectable Using Inspector and enabling it to watch focus it does seem to return the correct results for Edge, ie it knows if focus is in a password field .... which seems to suggest there is something wrong with my code ... but I've no idea what.